# Removing duplicate lines of text but have exceptions - Excel

Tags: excel, text, duplicates, formula

I have some lines of text that look as below. As you can see there is a duplicate of "**x1**". What I want to do in Excel is remove duplicates (eg. x1) but keep the word "**Title**" as it counts as a duplicate and it will be removed which is something I don't want.

```
Title
x1
Title
x2
Title
x3
Title
x1
Title
x4
```

I searched all over the internet about methods some of them including "data validation" or even formulas like the one below but none of these worked. So do you have any ideas on how can this be done?

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2, 1/((COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20, $A$2:$A$20)>1)*(COUNTIF($E$1:E1, $A$2:$A$20)=0)*(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$3, $A$2:$A$20)<>1)), $A$2:$A$20), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to deal with this I suppose but if the "Title" is always the every other row, you could simply use a do loop with a "+ 2" to determine the dups.  So for example, let's assume all this data is in column A starting in row 1:

```
x = 2
Range("C1").Formula = "=Count(A:A)"
y = range("C1")
Cells(x,2).Formula = "=Countifs(A:A, A1)"
Range(Cells(x,2)).Copy
Range(Cells(x + 1, 2), cells(y, 2)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
Do While x <= y
If Cells(x, 2) > 1 Then
Rows(x).Delete
x = x + 1 'Add 1 since you already deleted 1 row and only need to move to the next row at this point.
Else
x = x + 2 'Add 2 to ensure you don't delete the title row
End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized after searching a little further that there is no easy way to do this in Excel. And in some cases it is impossible. So I found a workaround with Sublime text which is much easier to do this.

1. Copy-paste the content from column A to Sublime text.
2. Then select the repeated content that you don't want to be removed and then ALT + F3. This will select all instances of that content.(HINT: Add one "space" before that text to avoid line merging when proceeding to deleting duplicates.
3. Inverse the selection to now select all the rest text/content.
4. Then go Edit > Permute Lines > Unique.... 
   5 . DONE!!